# Swagger is endlessly loading but never getting the data (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

Just like what the title says, the swagger is only **loading** when I execute.

[image]

Since startup.cs was not in the project folder when I created, everything is in my `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Package.Interfaces;
using Package.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<OperationsContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IContentRepository, ContentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPackageRepository, PackageRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI V1");
    });
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
app.Run();
```

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint inside the `api/content` endpoint? Does it hit?

Comment: when I run the code it says **Package.dll!Package.Models.OperationsContext.OperationsContext(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<Package.Models.OperationsContext> options) Line 16** in Call Stack, and that's it.

Comment: As per your latest comment Check your Dbcontext file and the connection string is it connecting to the Db properly

Comment: Also for properly setting up of swagger you can refer this link https://medium.com/@gerhardmaree/quickly-create-a-net-6-minimal-api-with-swagger-documentation-720d88db79fb

Comment: Yes, I am connecting the db server from MSSQL server so I used **Scaffold-DbContext** command to connect the db database and it it same as what I wrote for connection strings in **appsettings.json**

Comment: Try once after removing db code and run the code to cross verify ie comment the db connection file and connection string if it is not using the data from database

Comment: Are you saying comment the connectionstring line in program.cs?

Comment: are you able to hit your endpoint directly from browser without swagger. if yes then atleast you can be sure that there is no issue with your API and database connection. then you need to only focus on swagger part.

Comment: Try to change `api/content` to output a string, comment out the place where DbContext is used, and see if it can output normally. Can you share part of code about `api/content`?